# get/set moment of inertia of KX_GameObject

Tags: python, game-engine, rigid-body-simulation

Is there a way to set and/or get the rotational moments of inertia used by a rigid-body `KX_GameObject` at runtime?

I am trying to predict the change in angular rotation that will be effected by applying a known torque.

Comment: You can set mass, which has a relation to inertia. You can override the current velocities to override inertia forces. But I'm not sure what you want to achieve.

Comment: @Monster I am trying to predict the change in angular velocity by dividing a known torque by the moment of inertia of the object in order to find the angular acceleration that will result.

Comment: If I understand you correctly you do not want that the object rotates?

Comment: @Monster The moment of inertia is the resistance of an object to rotational acceleration on a given axis. It is generally expressed as a vector of the resistance along x, y, and z axes. I am trying to be able to get and/or set this vector.

Comment: Rigid body objects have some form of rotational inertia, as torque can be applied to the object, and the resulting acceleration will change depending on object dimensions and mass, but I see no way in KX_GameObject to retrieve or set this property of the object.

Comment: You can read the inertia but not set it: https://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_77_1/bge.types.KX_GameObject.html#bge.types.KX_GameObject.localInertia

Comment: Excellent, this is what I was looking for.
I'd seen this in the API but had assumed it was the current momentum vector of sorts.